# YEAR: YXXZ - currently

Tags: usage

How should I write this:

For instance, I want to emphasise that I work in company since 2017 and I have to write it in my resume. Something like this:

- Work in IMB: 2017-2021

However, it is imperative to not write "2021", for I have to work to 2023 and currently I work there.

How do I have to write?

What is more idiomatic:

- Work in IBM: 2017-*currently/so far/until now*

Answer (score 1):

I'd write:

> IBM: 2017–

or

> IBM: 2017–present

with an en-dash in between.

I'd use "present" over your choices because it's a noun, and a direct replacement for "specific year", but leaving a space after the en-dash is another normal way of indicating an ongoing time period.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing: *present* is the standard way to write this.  For example, _List your position and include the years you worked at the business in parentheses. If you are still working there, list the month and year you started and listed the “finish date” as “Present."_ (https://www.indeed.com/career-advice/resumes-cover-letters/resume-past-or-present-tense)